# pgbench custom data model in postgres

Tags: postgresql, benchmarking

I would like to benchmark a tpc-c like scenario but using my data model rather than the standard one that pgbench creates. I understand that you can run a custom script using the -f parameter.

If i run the following command if the database exists already ...
 `pgbench -rf ./script.sql -c 4 -j 2 -T 60 -n dbName`

I get the following output.

```
client 0 script 0 aborted in command 0 query 0: ERROR:  database "dbname" already exists
client 1 script 0 aborted in command 0 query 0: ERROR:  database "dbname" already exists
client 2 script 0 aborted in command 0 query 0: ERROR:  database "dbname" already exists
client 3 script 0 aborted in command 0 query 0: ERROR:  database "dbname" already exists
transaction type: ./script.sql
scaling factor: 1
query mode: simple
number of clients: 4
number of threads: 2
duration: 60 s
number of transactions actually processed: 0
Run was aborted; the above results are incomplete
```

If i run the same command where the database does not already exist I get the following output.

```
connection to database "ngm2" failed:
FATAL:  database "ngm2" does not exist
```

Which seems a little silly.

script.sql contains the following

```
BEGIN;
insert into table1 (field1) values
('{"data1":0,"data2":"","data2":"data4"}');
END;
```

Is this possible or am I locked into the data model that pgBench uses?
If there is another application that I can use to benchmark TPC-C like scenarios in postgres using my own data model that would be helpful information as well.

Comment: It is possible to use your own data model, but you have to initialize it yourself. It is basically impossible for the script you showed us to generate the error you showed us. It looks like the true contents of your script.sql is trying to create a database.

Comment: What do you mean initialize it myself? The only thing I can think of that I haven't done is grant a specific user permissions. So I create the database, create the table. Then run the pgbench to insert the records. Do I need to do something other than that? I will try and do it again.

Comment: Thank you @jjanes. You 100% correct. The script file I had, had some create database / create table statements. I had removed those but hadn't saved the file. That is quite embarrassing. If you want to answer it. I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks for knowing your stuff.